# Android objectanimator not animating

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator, android-vectordrawable

I have designed today two drawable's of the classic `arrow` and `hamburger` icon to recreate and understand `objectAnimator` in android. The problem occurs when no animation is played but the drawable is changed.

I have created `ic_backarrow.xml`:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path android:strokeColor="@color/blue_ripple"
        android:fillColor="@color/blue_ripple"
        android:pathData="@string/arrow" />

</vector>
```

Followed by `ic_menu.xml`:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path android:fillColor="@color/blue_ripple"
        android:pathData="@string/menu" />

</vector>
```

In `strings.xml` I have defined my path's to be more easy to follow:

```
<string name="arrow">M4,11 H20 V13 H4 V11 M4,11 L12,4 L13.5,5.5 L5.5,12.5 L4,11 M4,13 L12,20 L13.5,18.5 L7.2,13 L4,13</string>
<string name="menu">M3,6 H21 V8 H3 V6 M3,11 L21,11 L21,13 L3,13 L3,11 M3,16 L21,16 L21,18 L3,18 L3,16</string>
```

I also modified the paths to be able to animate the drawable's: arrow to menu and menu to arrow.

After I have created the `arrow_to_menu.xml` where I define the `objectAnimator`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:valueFrom="@string/arrow"
    android:valueTo="@string/menu"
    android:duration="@integer/duration"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:valueType="pathType" />
```

and the `menu_to_arrow.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:valueFrom="@string/menu"
    android:valueTo="@string/arrow"
    android:duration="@integer/duration"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:valueType="pathType" />
```

In drawable's I also defined the `animated-vector` with the initial `drawable` and the target `objectAnimator`:

File: `avd_arrow_to_menu.xml`:

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_backarrow">

    <target
        android:name="@string/tick"
        android:animation="@animator/arrow_to_menu" />

</animated-vector>
```

And also `avd_menu_to_arrow.xml`:

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu">

    <target
        android:name="@string/cross"
        android:animation="@animator/menu_to_arrow" />

</animated-vector>
```

In the project `layout` I have created an `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tick_cross"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

In the `class` file I look-up for the `ImageView` and import the `AnimatedVectorDrawable's`

```
arrowMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tick_cross);
menuToArrow = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.avd_menu_to_arrow);
arrowToMenu = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.avd_arrow_to_menu);

arrowMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        animate(arrowMenu);
    }
});
```

And when the `ImageView` is clicked, it should animate between `hamburger` icon and `arrow` icon:

```
public void animate(View view) {
    AnimatedVectorDrawable drawable = menu ? menuToArrow : arrowToMenu;
    arrowMenu.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    drawable.start();
    menu = !menu;
}
```

As I said before, there is no animation between arrow and hamburger icon. I tried to change `android:duration` to something bigger like 1000 or something small like 400 but I have the same result.

Sorry for the long post, I really needed to explain every step I done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give names to the `paths` in your `VectorDrawables`.
If we look at your first `AnimatedVectorDrawable`:

```
<animated-vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/ic_backarrow">

    <target
        android:name="@string/tick"
        android:animation="@animator/arrow_to_menu" />

</animated-vector>
```

The line `android:name="@string/tick"` specifies what part of the `VectorDrawable` you are trying to animate, but if we look at the `VectorDrawable`, no part of it has been given a name to match that.

To fix that, take the `ic_backarrow.xml` and add the appropriate name tag:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="48dp"
android:width="48dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
    android:name="@string/tick"
    android:strokeColor="@color/blue_ripple"
    android:fillColor="@color/blue_ripple"
    android:pathData="@string/arrow" />

</vector>
```

Then add the appropriate `@string/cross` name to the path in your other `VectorDrawable`.